# C# Service Reference error: A child element named 'element' with same key already exists

Tags: c#, web-services, wcf

I'm trying to add a service reference to my C# application and it's acting like I'm adding a duplicate service.

The service I'm trying to add xxx/wbMoveInSpecialService/MoveInSpecial.svc

For some reason, it thinks it's a duplicate of **CommunicationsPlatform.CommandService**.  I've searched the solution for "MoveInSpecial" and gotten no matches.  Any suggestions?

Line 83 of my config:

```
endpoint address="xxx/CommandService.svc" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_CommandService" contract="CommunicationsPlatform.CommandService" name="BasicHttpBinding_CommandService"
```

[image: duplicate endpoint points to line 83 of config]

[EDIT]
I checked the Config for a duplicate of the CommandService as reds had suggested.  Turns out there were multiple duplicate endpoints in the config file, deleting those duplicates let me add my new service.

So the error was complaining about duplicates that were already there (probably from a TFS merge), not that I as adding a duplicate endpoint.

Comment: You have two `<endpoint />` tags in your config file...

Comment: Not for MoveInSpecial.  That was the first thing I checked.

Comment: Might post the entire <endpoints> section of the config file.

Comment: There are 20+ endponts defined.  As I said, I verified that there are no other endpoints named MoveInSpecial. I know the wizard doesn't always clean things up correctly, that doesn't seem to be the case here.

Comment: this "name="BasicHttpBinding_CommandService"" how many?

Comment: I had same problem, and the thing was that I had endpoint defined in config file, and (because of lack of knowledge) I have created another endpoint programmatically with the same name. I didn't want to created it, I just wanted to modify it. Maybe you have it somewhere in the code

Comment: Ahhh ... that was the culprit.  I had hacked a solution (added the reference to a different project and then copied it in manually) which seemed to work.  This is a much better solution - thanks!